# Is there little more advanced alternative of "DC Proof"? (it's a proof assistant)

Tags: math-software, computer-assisted-proofs

So far I inspected several proof assistant:

1.DC Proof. The closest to my ideal yet still not exactly what I want (although I still have some hope that maybe I'm missing something). I'm glad that it can handle propositional logic, predicate logic and set theory (for example, it can prove non-existence of the universal set, while it's impossiblee to make such proof in "Proof Designer"), yet it seems to miss some logical rules of replacement and interference. For example, commutativity and associativity of some logical opreators, constructive dilemma, destructive dilemma, hypothetical syllogism, disjunctive syllogism, exportation, modus tollens, absorption, modus ponendo tollens. I guess at the end it's possible to finish a proof without all it, but they make it easier (at the least for me). Plus "Undo" command allows to take only one step back.

2.Coq. I suppose that this monstruosity can do everything that I can ever thinking of, but this is just too cool for me. In short, I don't feel to be educated enough to even start learning how to use it.

3.Proof Designer. Can be useful, but seems like it's suffering from overspecialization. It's created for set theory and doing logical proofs in it is perversion with big letter P.

4.Minlog. As far as I understand, this proof assistant uses so-called "minimal logic". In other words, not only I need to learn new kind of logic, but this logic is less powerfull? Sorry buddy, but you're out.

Comment: @dan-christensen Maybe you, as the creator of DC Proof, can answer this question?

Comment: “[DC Proof] seems to miss some logical rules of replacement and interference. For example, commutativity and associativity of some logical opreators, constructive dilemma, destructive dilemma, hypothetical syllogism, disjunctive syllogism, exportation, modus tollens, absorption, modus ponendo tollens.” I do not know DC Proof, but these rules may be derivable. It is highly improbable that they are underivable because then the logic is very weak and unsuitable for building mathematics. If they are derivable, then their statement equivalents will be theorems which you can use.

Comment: @beroal They ARE derivable. But, how far as I know, only for individual statements. In other words, you can't deduce a RULE of interference/replacement and then apply it universally, you deduce that for such and such specific statement such and such interference/replacement holds true. It's like if you had to prove commutativity of addition every time you wanted to use it.

Comment: @user161005: To be fair, if your axioms of PA, then you need to prove commutativity every time you want to use it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you mean Peano Axioms? And why can't I just prove commutativity one time as theorem and then use it everywhere?

Comment: @user161005: Yes. When you use a theorem that you proved, you effectively say "append this previous proof into my current proof". But formally speaking, if you just derive your proof from the axioms, well, then, there is no axiom stating that theorem. That's why we call it a theorem and not an axiom.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know the difference between a theorem and an axiom. This being said, even if it's theorem there is no reason to force a user to prove it if it's some basic and/or popular theorem. But DC proof doesn't even allow to prove theorem about commutativity inside given proof and then apply them to any relevant subsequent statements.

Comment: @user161005: Yes, of course, you can ask your proof verifier to allow you "load theorems", but you ultimately need to have that verified at one point or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that better alternative for DC Proof (and to even far more advanced proof assistants, like Coq) is method of structured proofs described in the following pappers:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/write-21st-century-proof/

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/how-to-write-a-proof/

I came to such conclusion after playing around with DC Proof. The reasons are following:

1.There are always limits to expressiveness of languages of proof assistants. For example, in DC Proof you can't directly apply constructive dilemma, although you can deduce that such logical construction is valid for given statements, but it's tedious.But even if DC Proof could do it, it would still be hard, for example, to formalize geometrical proofs from school course of geometry. In the end it means that either proof is impossible (like you can't prove that the Universal set doesn't exist in "Proof Designer" because you're forbidden from even mentioning the Universal set) or a proof becomes more complicated.

2.I want to do my proofs purely for myself, in order to better understand given theorem/lemma. So if some things are just TOO obvious for me it would be waste of time to formally explain in all details why it must be true. Although there is danger of overconfidence, but I think that it's possible to find the right balance between reasonable confidence and always describing in all details what and why is true. Strict formalization wouldn't allow such shortcuts.

Comment: The question asks for a proof assistant more convenient than DC Proof, but this self-answer you accepted seems to say "if your goal is not to use a proof assistant, but just to use technology to have more confidence in your proofs, do this instead". I was going to post an alternative not mentioned in the question, but I feel like I was misled as to what you were asking/what the point of this posting was.

Comment: @MarkS. I wanted proof assistant because I wanted to be more sure that my proofs are correct. My point is that while proof assistants can help to reach this goal to some extent, the method of structured proofs, without use of proof assistants, is better. Rejection of proof assistants isn't a goal, it's purely consequence of finding that there is better tool.

Comment: I often use the Axiom Rule to enter "theorems" (the stuff you are  fairly confident about and don't want to prove) and then use the built-in axioms to verify your thinking on the tricky bits.

Comment: From my own experience, writing formal geometric proofs using Tarski's axioms (not the typical proofs in North American high schools) is VERY difficult indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just confirmed that the following are derivable in the latest version of DC Proof 2.0 (released 2019-09-14) available free at my [homepage](https://www.dcproof.com):

- commutativity and associativity of AND (&) and OR (|)
- constructive dilemma
- destructive dilemma
- hypothetical syllogism
- disjunctive syllogism
- exportation
- modus tollens
- absorption
- modus ponendo tollens

To use a theorem derived in another proof, I use the Axiom Rule to insert that theorem at the beginning of a new proof. I also use it to introduce definitions. An axiom introduced by the user  in this way (as opposed a built-in axiom) differs from a Premise only in that it cannot be discharged, and that it must be inserted at the beginning of a proof before any Premise is introduced.